# Add pending for reply comment in console WordPress

Tags: comments

How do I add a pending comment option when writing a reply comment in WP Admin?
Reply to a comment, but keep it in "pending" status. Not a comment left by a visitor, but a comment written by an administrator in the WP Admin.

[image]

Please help me

Comment: You mean to put the reply comment you're writing into moderation?

Comment: Reply to a comment, but keep it in "pending" status. Not a comment left by a visitor, but a comment written by an administrator in the WP Admin.